# Trouble in binding ListView.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

In my `WPF` mvvm(light) project I have such problem : after binding of `ListView.SelectedItem` to my `ModelView`, I'm trying to change it from `ModelView`.It seems to be ok, but nothing happend at View :

XAML :

```
<ListView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOne}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
</ListView>

<ListView     ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myDataTemplateSelector}"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOne, Mode=TwoWay}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
</ListView>
```

MOdelView :

```
ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _EAItems = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
public ObservableObject _selectedOne;

public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return _EAItems;
            }
            set
            {
                _EAItems = value;
            }
        }

public ObservableObject SelectedOne 
        {
            get { return _selectedOne; }
            set 
            {

                if(_selectedOne != value)
                _selectedOne = value;

            }
        }
Select = new RelayCommand(() => 
            {
                if (qw == 15) { qw = 0; }else
                SelectedOne = Items[qw];
                qw++;
            });
```

Items is `ObservableCollection`.

I added another `Listview` and bind it to the same sources. When I change `SelctedItem` in one of `Listview`, it's displayed on another  , vise versa.

I looked thru alot similar solutions, and I can't figure what is wrong  :(

Comment: I can't find a reference, but I believe there is an implied of property change event when the source of the property change is the UI - that is why the example with 2 ListViews is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Clemens and blindmeis. The only fact is that the SelectedOne need to be the same class that the one set for the Collection. And with the MVVM-light libraries, the method is RaisePropertyChanged instead of OnPropertyChanged (if your viewModel inherit from ViewModelBase).

If your source contains ItemViewModels should use this code :

```
private ItemViewModel _selectedOne;

public ItemViewModel SelectedOne 
{
    get { return _selectedOne; }
    set 
    {

        if(_selectedOne != value)
        _selectedOne = value;

        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedOne");
    }
}
```

The reason why your collection don't need RaisePropertyChanged is that ObsvervableCollection class already contains it in a certain way.

Regards,

Kévin

Answer (score 2):

first you should also post the code for the binding for the ItemsSource, the ItemsSource property.

but the main problem is the you do not call PropertyChanged in your setter

```
    public ObservableObject SelectedOne 
    {
        get { return _selectedOne; }
        set 
        {

            if(_selectedOne != value)
            _selectedOne = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedOne ");//<-- otherwise the view dont know that the SelectedItem changed
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the binding work you would have to raise a [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event from the `SelectedOne` setter. The class that defines the `SelectedOne` property would have to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms133020).

Regardless of the *type* of the `SelectedOne` property (even if it is itself an ObservableObject), you have to raise a `PropertyChanged` event when the *value* of the property changes.

Comment: SelectedObject's type is ObservableObject which is already inherit PropertyChanged and PropertyChanging interfaces. It's implemented in MVVM-light libraries

Comment: That's not the point. It doesn't matter here what type the property is. The `SelectedOne` setter must raise a `PropertyChanged` event. See the sample code in @blindmeis' answer.

Comment: Sorry, but i can't see two ListViews. Where is the second one?

Comment: @SergSolohin see my comment on original question for explanation of 2 ListView behaviour

Comment: That won't work without any hidden magic. You either haven't posted all your relevant code or you're observing some kind of secondary effect. Binding two ListView's SelectedItem to a property that doesn't fire PropertyChanged (and is also not a dependency property) won't keep them in sync.